# GTest Automatic Mock Class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

For some time my old project used gmock_gen.py to generate automatically mocked classes (this is an old project from http://code.google.com/p/cppclean/ that it seems inactive and it depends on python2 that we don't want)

My question:
Is there anything on gtest environment that does the same as gmock_gen.py and supports python3, or what is the alternative to gmock_gen.py if we don't have or don't want to use python2?

Best regards,
Nuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the conversion to python3 is very simple.

You only need to do two things and only one is required (step 2.):

1. you can use the python tool 2to3 to convert the code from python 2 code into python 3 code (optional)
2. change only one line to prevent an exception on the execution of the scrip:

   gmock_gtest/generator/cpp/ast.py:908

   change from:

   ```
    def _GetNextToken(self):
        if self.token_queue:
            return self.token_queue.pop()
        return next(self.tokens)
   ```

   to

   ```
    def _GetNextToken(self):
        if self.token_queue:
            return self.token_queue.pop()
        return next(self.tokens, None)
   ```

and that will work.